# How to add menu to sort ascending and descending in controller codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

content my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AutoLoadDiv extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('ngoding/AutoLoad');
    }

    public function getData() {

        $this->load->library('table');
        $err = file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");
        $filestr = preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
        $arraySpacing = nl2br($filestr);
        $arr = explode("\n", $arraySpacing);

        $output = '<style> th, td {text-align: left; padding: 10px;} tr:nth-child(even){background-color#FFF;} tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#CCC;} </style>';
        $output .= '<table border="1px solid #dddddd;" >'; 
        $output .= '<tr><th>Date</th><tr>';
        for ($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $output.="<tr><td>$arr[$i]</td></tr>"; 
        }
        $output.="</table>"; 
        echo $output; 


        }
    }
```

Here code view after try to implementing Datatables but not working

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js">


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
            $("#table").load('AutoLoadDiv/getData')
            }, 5000);
            });
        </script>


        <style>

        </style>

        <title>Auto Load Page in Div using Jquery</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Auto Load Page in Div</h1>
            <div id="content">Please wait....</div>
            <div class="container">


                <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var table;
                table = $(document).ready(function() {

                    //datatables
                    table = $('#table').DataTable({

                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "order": [],

                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "<?php echo site_url('AutoLoadDiv/getData')?>",
                            "type": "POST"
                        },


                        "columnDefs": [
                            {
                                "targets": [ 0 ],
                                "orderable": false,
                            },
                        ],

                    });

                });

            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

After I implementing Datatables, result view like this :

https://ibb.co/keTQYe

I have problem to implementing my code to make menu like dropdown to ascending and descending like this example : https://ibb.co/chO2Bz, I want to implamenting html asc and dsc in controller, not in view ,if I click that menu is sort to ascending , if click that menu again is sort to descending?

Comment: can't you just use `array_reverse()` after splitting by `\n`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Check this out https://makitweb.com/sort-pagination-records-on-header-click-in-codeigniter/

Comment: You can also Datatables - https://datatables.net/

Comment: Seems like CodeIgniter not providing sorting feature in `table` library - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: how to implementing Datatables in controller Codeigniter

Comment: Try at your end first and come up with some code with your query. We will surely guide you to resolve your errors if it occurs.

Comment: My data content array, no DB  how implamenting array in Datatables

Comment: I try add Datatables in server side but not working

Comment: `$("#table").load('AutoLoadDiv/getData')` isn't the proper way of loading data into the table. you should really read the datatables ajax docs - it is very extensive. also note that datatables *requires* a json response (https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/). you can use a lib like this to gen it: https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

Comment: how to fix that , I'm search in google but not get solution